# bash argument case for args in $@

Tags: bash, shell

I have a script with a long list of OPTIONAL arguments. some have associated values.

Such as:

```
.script --first 2012-12-25 --last 2012-12-26 --copy --remove
.script --first 2012-12-25
```

Thus the following case statement:

```
for arg in "$@"
do
    case $arg in
        "--first" )
           START_DATE=$arg;;
        "--last" )
           END_DATE=$arg;;
        "--copy" )
           COPY=true;;
        "--remove" )
           REMOVE=true;;

# ... and so on
   esac
done
```

#### My problem:

that needs a increment `$arg+1` type statement to get the following arg (in some cases).

How is that possible?

I'm also happy to do a substring such `.script --first2012-12-25 --last2012-12-26`

and not sure how to proceed there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getopts cannot have optional arguments it seems. otherwise great.

my solution

loop the `$@` and setting a variable equal to `x=$arg`
do the case switch on that variable (rather than arg)

that worked fine for arguments of the type `--startdate 2012-12-25 --enddate 2012-12-29`

but did not work for `--remove` that has no following argument.

therefore tack on stuff (unlikely argument) onto the arg string.

leaving the following

```
argc="$@ jabberwhocky" 
echo $argc
x=0
# x=0 for unset variable
for arg in $argc
do
   case $x in
        "--start" )
          STARTDATE=$arg ;;
        "--end" )
          ENDDATE=$arg ;;
        "--copy" )
          COPY=true;;
        "--remove" )
          REMOVE=true;;
```

... and so on....

```
    esac
    x=$arg
done
```

Answer (score 34):

You can allow both --a=arg or -a arg options with a little more work:

```sh
START_DATE="$(date '+%Y-%m-%d')";
LAST_DATE="$(date '+%Y-%m-%d')";
while [[ $# -gt 0 ]] && [[ "$1" == "--"* ]] ;
do
    opt="$1";
    shift;              #expose next argument
    case "$opt" in
        "--" ) break 2;;
        "--first" )
           START_DATE="$1"; shift;;
        "--first="* )     # alternate format: --first=date
           START_DATE="${opt#*=}";;
        "--last" )
           LAST_DATE="$1"; shift;;
        "--last="* )
           LAST_DATE="${opt#*=}";;
        "--copy" )
           COPY=true;;
        "--remove" )
           REMOVE=true;;
        "--optional" )
           OPTIONAL="$optional_default";;     #set to some default value
        "--optional=*" )
           OPTIONAL="${opt#*=}";;             #take argument
        *) echo >&2 "Invalid option: $@"; exit 1;;
   esac
done
```

Note the --optional argument uses a default value if "=" is not used, else it sets the value in the normal way.

Comment: Better write `while [[ "$1" = --* ]]; do ` directly.

Comment: gniourf_gniourf: some configurations write errors if you use an undefined variable. The $# -gt avoids such.

Comment: FYI: I quote every variable expansion to avoid problems with command lines with --first="12 May 2012". As without quotes such change inside the script TO $1="--first=12" $2="May" $3=2012. Oops.

Comment: You're talking about the `unset` option? In this case, `set +u` will do. Then, if you really want to check `$#`, you could use bash arithmetic: `(($#>0))`.

Comment: Probably, the last variant meant:
`*) echo >&2 "Invalid option: $opt"; exit 1;;`

Answer (score 2):

Use `shift` in the end of each `case` statement.

Quote from a `bash` manual:

> shift [n]
>
> The positional parameters from n+1 ... are renamed to $1
>   ....  Parameters represented by the numbers $# down to $#-n+1 are
>   unset.  n must be a non-negative number less than or equal to $#.  If
>   n  is  0, no parameters are changed.  If n is not given, it is assumed
>   to be 1.  If n is greater than $#, the positional parameters are not
>   changed.  The return status is greater than zero if n is greater than
>   $# or less than zero; otherwise 0.

Comment: Yes, `shift` can be a solution, but not without some more work. `shift` affects `"$@"`, but it won't affect the `for` loop, which is working on a *copy* of `"$@"` evaluated at the top of the loop.

Answer (score 2):

`$@` is an array, & not a simple variable.

You can capture it to a local variable as `x=("$@")` & then use array x with indices as `0 to ($# - 1)`.

To access individual elements, use `${x[$i]}`. You can NOT directly use `${@[$i]}`, however.

So instead of `for arg in "$@"` loop, you will have `i=0; while [ $i -lt $# ]; do` loop.

Comment: `"$@"` is not an array. It is a special variable that expands to all the received arguments, correctly delimited (as opposed to `"$*"`, which joins all into one).

Comment: @LuisLavaire., yes it's an array. You can loop over it, you can slice it, reference 'n'th element from it. It's just that it is an immutable array. So, you cannot set any arbitrary entry like `a[5]=abcd`. You have to set the entire array for this `set -- v a l u e s`.

Comment: You can't loop over it. You even mention it yourself: _"You can NOT directly use `${@[$i]}`, however."_

Comment: You can loop. Just the syntax is different. Use `${!i}` instead of `${@[$i]}`. (I did not know this at the time of answering.)

Comment: The `${!...}` notation is for performing referential substitution. Strictly speaking, you can't iterate over `"$@"` (because the shell expands it, so all the shell will see after expansion is just strings, not an array), even when the aforementioned substitution seems to be looping over it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than one option, and especially options with values mixed with options without values, let [getopts](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/getopts.html) do the work for you.