# Reading $OPTARG for optional flags?

Tags: bash, getopts

I'd like to be able to accept both mandatory and optional flags in my script. Here's what I have so far.

```
#!bin/bash

while getopts ":a:b:cdef" opt; do
      case $opt in
        a ) APPLE="$OPTARG";;
        b ) BANANA="$OPTARG";;
        c ) CHERRY="$OPTARG";;
        d ) DFRUIT="$OPTARG";;
        e ) EGGPLANT="$OPTARG";;
        f ) FIG="$OPTARG";;
        \?) echo "Invalid option: -"$OPTARG"" >&2
            exit 1;;
        : ) echo "Option -"$OPTARG" requires an argument." >&2
            exit 1;;
      esac
    done
echo "Apple is "$APPLE""
echo "Banana is "$BANANA""
echo "Cherry is "$CHERRY""
echo "Dfruit is "$DFRUIT""
echo "Eggplant is "$EGGPLANT""
echo "Fig is "$FIG""
```

However, the output for the following:

```
bash script.sh -a apple -b banana -c cherry -d dfruit -e eggplant -f fig
```

...outputs this:

```
Apple is apple
Banana is banana
Cherry is 
Dfruit is 
Eggplant is 
Fig is
```

As you can see, the optional flags are not pulling the arguments with $OPTARG as it does with the required flags. Is there a way to read $OPTARG on optional flags without getting rid of the neat ":)" error handling?

### =======================================

**EDIT:** I wound up following the advice of Gilbert below. Here's what I did:

```
#!/bin/bash

  if [[ "$1" =~ ^((-{1,2})([Hh]$|[Hh][Ee][Ll][Pp])|)$ ]]; then
    print_usage; exit 1
  else
    while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
      opt="$1"
      shift;
      current_arg="$1"
      if [[ "$current_arg" =~ ^-{1,2}.* ]]; then
        echo "WARNING: You may have left an argument blank. Double check your command." 
      fi
      case "$opt" in
        "-a"|"--apple"      ) APPLE="$1"; shift;;
        "-b"|"--banana"     ) BANANA="$1"; shift;;
        "-c"|"--cherry"     ) CHERRY="$1"; shift;;
        "-d"|"--dfruit"     ) DFRUIT="$1"; shift;;
        "-e"|"--eggplant"   ) EGGPLANT="$1"; shift;;
        "-f"|"--fig"        ) FIG="$1"; shift;;
        *                   ) echo "ERROR: Invalid option: \""$opt"\"" >&2
                              exit 1;;
      esac
    done
  fi

  if [[ "$APPLE" == "" || "$BANANA" == "" ]]; then
    echo "ERROR: Options -a and -b require arguments." >&2
    exit 1
  fi
```

Thanks so much, everyone. This works perfectly so far.

Comment: Durian is a fruit starting with D ;)

Comment: Isn't donut a fruit? It's very sweet.

Comment: Dates *Phoenix dactylifera* are another candi-DATE...

Comment: I assumed "DFRUIT" was shorthand for dragon fruit ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most shell getopts have been annoying me for a long time, including lack of support of optional arguments.

But if you are willing to use "--posix" style arguments, visit [bash argument case for args in $@](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14062895/bash-argument-case-for-args-in/14063511#14063511)

Comment: Thanks so much. I wound up really going at it with your solution. I have edited my original post to show what I did. Thanks!

Answer (score 73):

`:` means "takes an argument", not "mandatory argument". That is, an option character not followed by `:` means a flag-style option (no argument), whereas an option character followed by `:` means an option with an argument.

Thus, you probably want

```
getopts "a:b:c:d:e:f:" opt
```

If you want "mandatory" options (a bit of an oxymoron), you can check after argument parsing that your mandatory option values were all set.

Answer (score 10):

It isn't easy... Any "optional" option arguments must actually be required as far as `getopts` will know. Of course, an optional argument must be a part of the same argument to the script as the option it goes with. Otherwise an option `-f` with an optional argument and an option `-a` with a required argument can get confused:

```
# Is -a an option or an argument?
./script.sh -f -a foo

# -a is definitely an argument
./script.sh -f-a foo
```

The only way to do this is to test whether the option and its argument are in the same argument to the script. If so, OPTARG is the argument to the option. Otherwise, OPTIND must be decremented by one. Of course, the option is now required to have an argument, meaning a  character will be found when an option is missing an argument. Just use another `case` to determine if any options are required:

```
while getopts ":a:b:c:d:e:f:" opt; do
    case $opt in
        a) APPLE="$OPTARG";;
        b) BANANA="$OPTARG";;
        c|d|e|f)
            if test "$OPTARG" = "$(eval echo '$'$((OPTIND - 1)))"; then
                OPTIND=$((OPTIND - 1))
            else
                 case $opt in
                     c) CHERRY="$OPTARG";;
                     d) DFRUIT="$OPTARG";;
                     ...
                esac
            fi ;;
        \?) ... ;;
        :)
             case "$OPTARG" in
                 c|d|e|f) ;; # Ignore missing arguments
                 *) echo "option requires an argument -- $OPTARG" >&2 ;;
            esac ;;
        esac
    done
```

This has worked for me so far.

Answer (score 7):

For bash, this is my favorite way to parse/support cli args. I used getopts and it was too frustrating that it wouldn't support long options. I do like how it works otherwise - especially for built-in functionality.

```
usage()
{
    echo "usage: $0 -OPT1 <opt1_arg> -OPT2"
}
while [ "`echo $1 | cut -c1`" = "-" ]
do
    case "$1" in
        -OPT1)
                OPT1_ARGV=$2
                OPT1_BOOL=1
                shift 2
            ;;
        -OPT2)
                OPT2_BOOL=1
                shift 1
            ;;
        *)
                usage
                exit 1
            ;;
esac
done
```

Short, simple. An engineer's best friend!

I think this can be modified to support "--" options as well...

Cheers =)

Answer (score 5):

#### Understanding `bash`'s `getopts`

The `bash` manual page (quoting the version 4.1 manual) for `getopts` says:

> `getopts optstring name`*`[args]`*
>
> `getopts` is used by shell scripts to parse positional parameters. *optstring* contains
>   the option characters to be recognized; if a character is followed by a
>   colon, the option is expected to have an argument, which should be separated
>   from it by white space. The colon (‘:’) and question mark (‘?’) may not be
>   used as option characters. Each time it is invoked, `getopts` places the next
>   option in the shell variable *name*, initializing *name* if it does not exist, and the
>   index of the next argument to be processed into the variable `OPTIND`. `OPTIND`
>   is initialized to 1 each time the shell or a shell script is invoked. When an
>   option requires an argument, `getopts` places that argument into the variable
>   `OPTARG`. The shell does not reset `OPTIND` automatically; it must be manually
>   reset between multiple calls to `getopts` within the same shell invocation if a
>   new set of parameters is to be used.
>
> When the end of options is encountered, `getopts` exits with a return value
>   greater than zero. `OPTIND` is set to the index of the first non-option argument,
>   and *name* is set to ‘?’.
>
> `getopts` normally parses the positional parameters, but if more arguments are
>   given in *args*, `getopts` parses those instead.
>
> `getopts` can report errors in two ways. If the first character of *optstring* is a
>   colon, silent error reporting is used. In normal operation diagnostic messages
>   are printed when invalid options or missing option arguments are encountered.
>   If the variable `OPTERR` is set to 0, no error messages will be displayed, even if
>   the first character of *optstring* is not a colon.
>
> If an invalid option is seen, `getopts` places ‘?’ into *name* and, if not silent,
>   prints an error message and unsets `OPTARG`. If `getopts` is silent, the option
>   character found is placed in `OPTARG` and no diagnostic message is printed.
>   If a required argument is not found, and `getopts` is not silent, a question mark
>   (‘?’) is placed in *name*, `OPTARG` is unset, and a diagnostic message is printed. If
>   `getopts` is silent, then a colon (‘:’) is placed in *name* and `OPTARG` is set to the
>   option character found.

Note that:

1. The leading colon in the option string puts `getopts` into silent mode; it does not generate any error messages.
2. The description doesn't mention anything about optional option arguments.

I'm assuming that you are after functionality akin to:

```
script -ffilename
script -f
```

where the flag `f` (`-f`) optionally accepts an argument.  This is not supported by `bash`'s `getopts` command.  The POSIX function `getopt()` barely supports that notation.  In effect, only the last option on a command line can have an optional argument under POSIX.

#### What are the alternatives?

In part, consult [Using `getopts` in `bash` shell script to get long and short command-line options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402377/using-getopts-in-bash-shell-script-to-get-long-and-short-command-line-options).

The GNU [`getopt`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/getopt) (singular!) program is a complex beastie that supports long and short options and supports optional arguments for long options (and uses GNU [`getopt(3)`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html).  Tracking its source is entertaining; the link on the page at die.net is wrong; you'll find it in a sub-directory under ftp://ftp.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux (without the `-ng`).  I've not tracked down a location at http://www.gnu.org/ or http://www.fsf.org/ that contains it.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts ":a:b:c:d:e:f:" opt; do
      case $opt in
        a ) APPLE="$OPTARG";;
        b ) BANANA="$OPTARG";;
        c ) CHERRY="$OPTARG";;
        d ) DFRUIT="$OPTARG";;
        e ) EGGPLANT="$OPTARG";;
        f ) FIG="$OPTARG";;
        \?) echo "Invalid option: -"$OPTARG"" >&2
            exit 1;;
        : ) echo "Option -"$OPTARG" requires an argument." >&2
            exit 1;;
      esac
    done
echo "Apple is "$APPLE""
echo "Banana is "$BANANA""
echo "Cherry is "$CHERRY""
echo "Dfruit is "$DFRUIT""
echo "Eggplant is "$EGGPLANT""
echo "Fig is "$FIG""
```