# Add seconds option to positional parameters in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, parameters, case

Hello im writing a bash code which has some positional parameters but whats the best approach to add an optional seconds parameter which will allow some function to run for x seconds?
This is what code looks like:

```
doaction()
{
(run a process)
}

while [ $# -gt -0 ]; do
  case "$1" in
  --action|-a)
     doaction ;;
  --seconds|-s)
     ???????? $2
     shift ;;
  esac
shift
done
```

After x seconds kill process.
Also what happens when i run the script like
    ./script -s 10 -a
instead of 
    ./script -a -s 10

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the [`timeout`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/timeout-invocation.html) command is probably useful here. However, this only works on a script separate from the one that is currently running (as far as I can tell).

For your second question, the way you currently have things written, if you use `./script -a -s 10` then the result would be that the action would run before the delay is set. You can fix this by using a flag to indicate that the action should be executed, and you can ensure that the timeout is set (if at all) before the execution.

Here is my suggestion for a possible solution:

```
while [ $# -gt -0 ]; do
    case "$1" in
    --action|-a)
        action=true;;
    --seconds|-s)
        time="$2"
        shift;;
    esac;
    shift
done

if $action; then
    timeout $time /path/to/action.sh
else
    # do something else
fi
```

Where `/path/to/action.sh` is the location of the script that you want to run for a specific amount of time. You can test that the script exits after the specified number of seconds by replacing the script with the bash command `top` or something else which runs indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "getopts" to solve your problem. You might find the [information on this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18414054/bash-getopts-reading-optarg-for-optional-flags) to be useful for your scenario.

Comment: please add relevent information in the post , and use the link as only source.